# Does 'chicken dinner games' refer to all battle royal type games?

Tags: meaning

Chicken dinner games or 吃鸡游戏 seem to have become a kind of *genre* thanks to **PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS**.

What originally only only referred to one, specific, title can now be seen in sentences like

> 各种各样的吃鸡游戏

and

> 吃鸡游戏大全

The question is what specifically is this genre? Battle royal or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winner winner...

I think 吃鸡游戏 refers to games that:

1. In first person POV
2. Action oriented
3. Put x players together and make them kill each other till there's only one left

Mostly just things that look like PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS.

Answer (score 1):

If you survive in PLAYERUNKNOWN’S BATTLEGROUND at last. There will be a sentence on your screen: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner! which is translated as “大吉大利，晚上吃鸡”。According to this,吃鸡 maybe a Battle royal as you have described.